# Add column based on pattern matching

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns and would like to fill the second column (which is currently empty) based on the value of the first. If there is "_ab", "_cd" or "_ef" at any position in the first column, "ab", "cd" or "ef" respectively should be in column 2.

That's how it should look:

```
c1         c2
s_d_ab     ab
a_cd_aa    cd
s_sar_ef   ef
```

In **Excel** I would copy down the formula `=IF(FIND("_ab",A1), "ab", "")`, then hide the rows where there was no match and overwrite the formula with `=IF(FIND("_ab",A1), "ab", "")`. And so on. Not the most elegant method but it works.

What is the best way to approach this in R?

I managed to get a vector of logical values where the conditions apply (`grepl("_abc", data$c1)`) but don't know how to set the value of the second column.

Comment: Can you explain in words how you pick which section of each string you're picking?  Why isn't the third example `aa`?

Comment: @Justin, I edited my question: If there is "_ab", "_cd" or "_ef" **at any position** in the first column, "ab", "cd" or "ef" respectively should be in column 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sub` function:

```
x <- c('s_d_ab', 'a_cd_aa', 's_sar_ef')
sub('.*_(ab|cd|ef).*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "ab" "cd" "ef"
```